# Ng-click need double click why

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a little problem : ng-click working if only i do a double-click oO i don't understand, what is wrong ?

This is my controller

```
function MapCtrl($scope) {

    if(navigator.onLine){
        $scope.online = true;
    } else {
        $scope.offline = true;
    }

    /* text */
    $scope.reloadText = "Reload";
    $scope.reloadingText = "Reload in progress";
    $scope.offlineText = "not online";


    $scope.reloadMap = function() {
        $scope.reload = true;
        $scope.online = false;
        $scope.offline = false;
    }
}
```

and my html :

```
<section class="myPanel panel-padding" ng-controller="MapCtrl">

    <div id="myMap">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="offline">{{offlineText}}</div>

        <p ng-show="reload"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> <span>{{reloadingText}}</span></p>

        <div id="map" ng-show="online"></div>
        <div id="mapControls">
            <ul>
                <li ng-hide="reload">
                    <button type="button" ng-click="reloadMap()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">{{reloadText}}</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

i don't understand why i need to double-click, i want it back to normal :/

Comment: Can you define what "working" means?

Comment: i must do a double click  not onyl one click, to active ng-click function

Comment: Single click works based on the code you are showing: http://plnkr.co/edit/cvNVW8dKz1JO3mwMCRQF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

`reloadMap` sets `reload` to true und your `<li>` has `ng-hide="reload"` meaning it is hidden when `reload` is true. So when you lick once the button should vanish. Clicking a second time or making a doubleclick makes the button visible again.

Comment: You should not lick the button.